# I am getting HTML code instead of JSON in response

Tags: android, json

When I'm triggering my URL ([URL here](http://health.ultimatefreehost.in/E-H/production/mobile/mFeedList)) with HttpUrlConnection in android, in the response it is giving below HTML code instead of JSON.Please help me out with this.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
    <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f
        <d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("f1f002aa0df1b14d95e07de0f61fa7da");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://health.ultimatefreehost.in/E-H/production/mobile/mFeedList?i=1";
        </script>
        <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is my Android code.

```
URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // read the response
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        response = convertStreamToString(in);
```

Note: But in browser it is giving proper JSON response.

Comment: Talk to whoever maintains the Web server. Nobody else on the planet can help you. Note that when I request that URL via `curl`, I get an HTTP 403 Forbidden response.

Comment: what is the value of `reqUrl`?

Comment: If you disable JavaScript in your browser, you can't see the JSON. You'll see this HTML rendered.

Comment: The server serves a HTML page which uses javascript to load another page. This "works" in browser but nowhere else. Tell the administrator to use 301 redirect instead.

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick I literally just discovered as I was scouring the Internet for solutions was to go to the URL in phone's browser before opening your Android application. Even if you close your browser first it should work. I don't know why this works. It may be since the phones browser has accessed the file to view the JSON Object/Array that the server somehow knows to pass the information along to the app that uses the same device? Will test further and see where it goes, but for now my app is working, and this trick will be the first thing I try the next time I get these errors.